# Exchange 2019 Onprem configuring monitoring alerts

Tags: exchange-server

Dear community experts.

Do you know if there is a way to create an alert that will send an email notification (using an external email account), in case that the exchange server has not receive any emails from more than 15 minutes for example?

Thank you in advance,

Jose G Diaz

It seems that more of the solution is using third party solutions but not sure if there is a power shell script or any other work around.